# How to kill a ping on a webshell?

Tags: linux, shell

I am using a web shell to test ping on my router and then I cannot kill the process...since `control + c` doesn't work via web shell. I tried `kill ping` and it didn't work...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what kind of web shell you are using. If it is based on linux, you can launch a ping command with a limited number of ECHO_REQUEST packets to send. I mean, instead of launch:

```
ping www.example.org
```

You can do:

```
ping -c 3 www.example.org
```

This command will launch only three ECHO_REQUEST packets to the destination.

If it's based on windows, the `ping www.example.org` command launchs by default only 4 packets.

Answer (score 1):

Get the process id of ping. Use [ps](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) to do this

e.g.

```
ps -ef | grep ping
```

Then

```
kill -9 <process id from above>
```

Comment: This might work for other web shell but mine doesn't seem to output anything with `ps -ef`... it shows -e is not an option, and even with `ps` it doesn't output anything...

Comment: There is no ping process at stretch debian. Bu it is still running through ssh.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command,

```
$ ps aux | grep ping
$ kill -9 (ping_pid)
```

Comment: This might work for other web shell but mine doesn't seem to output anything with ps aux...and even with ps it doesn't output anything...because I guess the ping has occupied the pipeline.